# Geocoding method looks right, but I always get 0 0 as my coordinates

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit, geocoding

This shouldnt be this hard... I'm just trying to geocode an address string so I can zoom to that address on the map on `viewDidLoad`, but every time I run the geocoding method I get 0 0 as my lat and long.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressOfSelected completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
         return;
     }

     if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

         CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
         self.shackCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
     }
}];

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = self.shackCoords.latitude;
region.center.longitude = self.shackCoords.longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = .05;
region.span.longitudeDelta = .05;

[self.mapView setRegion:region];
```

`shackCoords` is just a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps your address just can't be geocoded?

Comment: I am running it in the ios simulator, could that be a problem??

Comment: Move your setRegion code to _inside_ the geocoder's completion block.

Comment: and the region creation stuff I assume?

Comment: Yes, after self.shackCoords is set.  The geocoder method runs asynchronously.

Comment: HAHAHA you are freaking brilliant! Ive been trying to get that one to work for DAYS!!

Comment: Note that you should probably `dispatch_async` to the main queue, or `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to set the region on the map view. Changing UIView state on a background thread is a bad idea.